# Creating view in oracle using multiple queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, database-view

I have 2 tables:

```
create table my_users
( userid number,
  username varchar(20)
 );

create table all_users
( userid number,
  username varchar(20)
 );
```

I want to create a **view** which is equivalent to:

```
select * from all_users;
MINUS
select * from my_users;
```

However, I'm getting an error when I try to create the view using the following:

```
create of replace view 'vw_users' as
select * from all_users;
MINUS
select * from my_users;
```

I'm using Oracle12c database.

Comment: **What** error? Apart from having an extra semicolon after the first branch? And having the view name in single quotes (instead of double quotes which will make it a quoted identifier, which will cause you pain later)? (And 'of' instead of 'or', as Gurv mentioned)

Comment: `create or replace`

Comment: Error starting at line 3 in command:
MINUS
Error report:
Unknown Command
>>Query Run In:Query Result 1

Comment: yu have just a tipo as GurV tell you .  you musr use   `or`  instead of `of`

Comment: Don't edit the question to fix the problems you're being told about - it invalidates existing answers. Although it that is now actually the code you ran, and that was the only error you got, then the issue was only the semicolon after all...

Comment: I had used "or" in the db. the typo occurred while typing the question here. That's why I edited the question to reflect the actual query I ran. The error was of the semicolon and single quotes as everyone pointed out. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Three typos:

- `of` in `create of replace`
- semicolon in `select * from all_users;`
- view name in single quotes

Try this:

```
create or replace view "vw_users" as
select * from all_users
MINUS
select * from my_users;
```